# CSS arrow hides during jQuery slideUp or slideDown animation

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div with an arrow on top created using CSS:

```
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    background: #88b7d5;
    border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-left: -36px;
}
```

To show this div, I'm using a simple `$('.arrow_box').slideDown();` jQuery animation. The problem is that while the div is animating, the arrow is hidden, then as soon as the animation is complete the arrow shows abruptly. I want the arrow to be visible during the animation.

The arrow is shown using `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements, so I thought maybe jQuery uses pseudo elements during the animation, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Here is a jsFiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/m9s9ouok/

Comment: I believe this is because `slideDown()` uses `overflow:hidden` to keep content from overflowing while it animates the height of the element. The side effect is that your arrow is also hidden.

Comment: @showdev you're right! I added `overflow: visible !important;` to the `.arrow_box` class and the arrow is visible during the animation.

Comment: But then the content overflows your box. I suggest an additional inner element with `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Thanks. Actually in my case it looks fine as-is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery's `slideDown()` uses `overflow:hidden` to prevent content from overflowing while it animates the element's height.

I had success by forcing the element's overflow to be visible (by using !important) and adding an inner element whose overflow is hidden.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.arrow_box').slideDown(2000);
  });
});
```

```css
.arrow_box {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  background: #88b7d5;
  border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: visible!important;
}
.arrow_box .inner {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.arrow_box:after,
.arrow_box:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.arrow_box:after {
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #88b7d5;
  border-width: 30px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
  border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5;
  border-width: 36px;
  margin-left: -36px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Reveal</a>

<div class="arrow_box">
  <div class="inner">
    content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```