# Psuedo-Element Triangle During JQuery Slide

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm making a login box which slides out via JQuery, I'm using a pseudo-element to position a triangle on top. I've also tried placing the triangle there the normal way (with a traditional divider), so I assume the issue is with the border and not the pseudo-element.

The triangle does not appear until the slide is complete.

```
.mobiles-login {
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 89px;
    top: 112px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 16px auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.mobiles-login:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: -15px;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #656565;
}
```

https://codepen.io/cohen-coombe/pen/MWweEVB

[CSS arrow hides during jQuery slideUp or slideDown animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792409/css-arrow-hides-during-jquery-slideup-or-slidedown-animation) suggests setting overflow to visible !important, with an inner element with the overflow to invisible. This half worked, however the inner element's hidden overflow has no effect https://codepen.io/cohen-coombe/pen/OJVXOvw

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my option, maybe it will be useful:

https://codepen.io/roman-seredenko/pen/poJbpKR

I have added padding and put the arrow in that space. The shadow I have put in an additional div.

```
.mobiles-login {
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 89px;
    top: 112px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;

}
.mobiles-login-inner { box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24); }
.mobiles-login:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 0px;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #656565;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect.

Comment: @CitrisLemon You are welcome! Vote up if it's useful ;)